# Vue 3 Using computed object to get image info works until I render the value in template, then becomes NaN

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, computed-properties

I have an app that displays image arrays. Before the image is displayed I need to adjust cropping based upon the image dimensions. When I load the image in a vue child component, I use a computed function (arrow or regular) and in the browser's inspect vue extension the object value are there and correct. But when I attempt to use a computed object's parameter, the result are zero or Nan. I used both the standard computed function and the arrow computed function. Both results are the same.

```
script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';

const prop = defineProps({
    image: String,
    numberOfImages: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
});

const getDimensions = computed(function () {
    get: {
        const newImg = new Image();
        newImg.src = image_path(prop.image);
        newImg.onload = function () {
        }
        // returning an object
        return {
            nHeight: newImg.naturalHeight,
            nWidth: newImg.naturalWidth,
            nAspect: newImg.naturalWidth / newImg.naturalHeight,
            nPortrait: (newImg.naturalWidth > newImg.naturalHeight) ? false : true,
        };
    };
});
</script>

<template>
       <div>
            <span v-if="getDimensions.nPortrait">This is a portrait Image<br /></span>
            <span v-else>This is a NOT portrait Image<br /></span>

            <span>This Image Height:
                {{ getDimensions.nHeight }}
            </span>
            <img class="w-full h-full
                        object-fill
                        object-center
                        rounded-lg"
            :src="image_path(prop.image)" alt=""
            >
        </div>
</template>
```

The code seems to work fine until I add the span tags. Then the results are zero or Nan

I first tried it as an arrow function but no difference in result.
I guess being a newbie - I just don't have a clue whats happening here to cause the NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the properties of `newImg` before it has loaded its src, so the dimensions are all empty. Note that the computed will update when `prop.image` changes, but not when `newImage` changes, as it is not a reactive reference.

To resolve the issue, turn the computed into a watcher and use the `onload` to wait for the image:

```
const dimensions = ref({})

const loadImageDimensions = async (imageSrc) => {
  if (!imageSrc){
    return {}
  }
  const newImg = new Image()
  newImg.src = imageSrc
  await new Promise(resolve => newImg.onload = resolve)
  return {
    nHeight: newImg.naturalHeight,
    nWidth: newImg.naturalWidth,
    nAspect: newImg.naturalWidth / newImg.naturalHeight,
    nPortrait: (newImg.naturalWidth <= newImg.naturalHeight),
  }
}
watch(
 () => props.image,
 async () => dimensions.value = await loadImageDimensions(props.image),
 { immediate: true }
)
```

Note that you should not use a computed for `dimensions` since it is set through an async function, and [computed properties should not have side-effects.](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#best-practices)

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thank you Moritz Ringler, that solved my problem!